# Why was Rivka asked for consent after closing the deal?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, marriage, rashi, parashat-chaye-sara

> Then Laban and Bethuel answered, “...**Here is Rebekah before you; take her and go, and let her be a wife to your master’s son**...” ... The servant brought out objects of silver and gold, and garments, and gave them to Rebekah; and he gave presents to her brother and her mother. Then he and the men with him ate and drank, and they spent the night.

> ... When they arose the next morning, ... her brother and her mother said, “...Let us call the girl and ask for her reply.”  [Genesis.24.49-59](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.24.49-59?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0)

Rashi infers that the question was Halachic, but *according to Rashi's view*, then why was she asked after the deal was closed?

Comment: From the Scriptural text it does not seem that they asked her about the marriage, which, as you say, was already sealed. They were just asking her whether she wanted to go immediately.

Comment: @Alex Correct, that's why I referred specifically to Rashi as he contradicts the plaint meaning.

Answer (score 1):

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.24.57?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=bi) says "אין משיאין את האישה אלא מדעתה", a woman is not be married without her consent. This would seem to refer to the nissuin stage of marriage, when she enters the house of her husband (as was the case with Rivka). The "marriage" that was already done was the kiddushin, the betrothal, which can, at least in some cases, be done without the consent of the girl.

Comment: WOW, I liked your way of differentiating the two. So you think that a girl can be Makudeshet but if she does not want to go any further... happens what?

Comment: She can make herself an aguna. I don't know the halacha, but there is a mishna in Ketubos (I think) about if the father not being able to come up with the support he promised that the girl can demand a get, but if she prevents the nissuin she can not demand a get.